# Laravel /w Bootstrap PDF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, pdf

I have made a PDF output in Laravel with DoomPDF package. However, the first row of the table seems to be misplaced, and only on first paper. Does anyone know why?

Controller:

```
public function printPDF(PDF $pdf)
{
    $users = User::all();
    $pdf->loadView('pdf.index', compact('users'));
    return $pdf->setOrientation('landscape')->setPaper('A4')->stream();
}
```

Layout file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td><strong>{{$user->name}}</strong></td>
            <td>{{$user->address}} <br> {{$user->city}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->phone_private}} <br> {{$user->phone_work}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}} <br> {{$user->email_private}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->oib}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: So the view `pdf.index` contains only that `<table>` and its contents and no other markup?

Comment: No, it is full html. Head has bootstrap dependencies loading, and that's about it. Updated

Comment: What happen if you try to display the view in your browser and not in a PDF?

Comment: It displays from side to side, correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be [an issue with Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1103) which Laravel DomPDF uses internally to generate the PDF files. It can be easily fixed by adding this CSS rule to your view file:

```
<style>
    thead:before, thead:after,
    tbody:before, tbody:after,
    tfoot:before, tfoot:after
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

There was a [fix committed for this bug](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/commit/9af6eab022f9ba63d5c469ead272e8d8f6cb33e4) about a week ago, but it's for `dompdf/dompdf` v0.7 and [the stable v0.6.1 release of `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#v0.6.1) uses the older `dompdf/dompdf` v0.6. So if you want to use stable releases, you can use the CSS fix above until `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` v0.7 is finalized.